# Does (!(i % j)) mean not modulus of i and j = 0?

Tags: c++, modulo

```
int main()
{
 int i,j;

 for (i=1; i<=25; i++)
 {
  for (j=2; j<= i/2; j++)
   if (!(i%j)) break;
  if (j>i/2) cout << i << "\n";
 }
 return 0;
}
```

This program (not written by me) outputs the prime numbers from 1 to 25, including 1 even though 1 isnt prime.

I am having trouble with this line: `if (!(i%j)) break;`

Does this say "not modulus of i and j = 0?

Comment: The typical definition of primeness is that `n` is prime if it only has the factors of 1 and `n`. What definition of primeness are you using that 1 is not prime?

Comment: 1 is indeed not prime: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumber.html

Comment: "1 was formerly considered prime by some mathematicians, using the definition that a prime is divisible only by one and itself. 
However, this complicates the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, so modern definitions exclude units. The last professional mathematician to publicly label 1 a prime number was Henri Lebesgue in 1899."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`!(i%j)` is the same as `(i%j)==0`, or "i is divisible by j"

Answer (score 3):

The two following lines are essentially identical (as far as logic goes):

```
if (!(i%j))
if ((i % j) == 0)
```

The way I'd read the first line to make it clearer is "if there is not a remainder from `i/j`", ie, `i` is divisible by `j`.